# Extract a .pem file from an existing .ppk or from the server?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, putty, keys, puttygen

So I use windows and so when I first setup my server I had a pem key that I converted into a PPK using puttyGen. Now I no longer have the pem and need to access the server from a mac which uses .pem files. Is there any way to extract the .pem from the .ppk file OR is there anyway to download a new .pem file once I am on  the server via the ppk. Thanks for any info

Comment: take a look in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475069/use-ppk-file-in-mac-terminal-to-connect-to-remote-connection-over-ssh

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy the putty key to your mac
2. Install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) (if not installed)
3. Install putty command-line on your mac

   ```
   brew install putty
   ```
4. Extract your private key

   ```
   puttygen id_dsa.ppk -O private-openssh -o id_dsa
   ```
5. Extract your public key

   ```
   puttygen id_dsa.ppk -O public-openssh -o id_dsa.pub
   ```
6. Move the extracted keys to your $HOME/.ssh

Source: [How to convert .ppk key to OpenSSH key under Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/232362/how-to-convert-ppk-key-to-openssh-key-under-linux)